# Using map to create dataframe causes Pickling Error

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a bit of background, I am trying to match rows in one dataframe (`df1`) with similar rows in a different dataframe (`df2`). I want to end up with a dataframe which has every row from `df1` and a copy of `df2`'s rows for every row.

For example, I have 2 dataframes created like so:

```
  df1     df2
+-----+ +-----+
|value| |value|
+-----+ +-----+
|    0| |    2|
|    1| |    3|
+-----+ +-----+
```

(these are `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame` dataframes)
The final dataframe should look like this:

```
+-----+
|value|
+-----+
|    0| <- from df1
|    2| <- clone of df2
|    3|
|    1| <- from df1
|    2| <- clone of df2
|    3|
+-----+
```

The way I am attempting to create this dataframe is through a map and union. The first step I attempted was to create a list of duplicates of `df2` that I could then union with `df1` to create my desired dataframe.

```
def foo(row):
  return df2.limit(2)

listOfCopies = df1.rdd.map(foo)
print(listOfCopies.take(2))
```

I expected the output of `listOfCopies.take(2)` to be a list of 2 dataframes, however instead I get the error `PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: When you try to map the function onto the rdd, pyspark tries to pickle the function. The function has a global variable, `df2` that can't be pickled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As PMende commented, I could not find a way to work with `df2` from inside a function mapping `df1`. Instead, I ended up using a series of joins to accomplish the task.

Spark's ML pipeline function `approxSimilarityJoin` does what I want, although it is meant for cases where `df1` and `df2` have a column to be compared, such as a string or a hash.